# How to remove the origin label?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-1.5)(7,1.5)
\psaxes[Dx=90,dx=\psPiH,xunit=\psPi,xlabelFactor={}^\circ]{->}(0,0)(-2.2,-1.5)(2.2,1.5)
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic,plotpoints=100]{-7}{7}{sin(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

How to remove the `0` label at the origin?

Comment: Is this a problem with you? I think 100% you CAN do it by yourself. Hmm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `showorigin` key to false:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-1.5)(7,1.5)
\psaxes[Dx=90,dx=\psPiH,xunit=\psPi,xlabelFactor={}^\circ,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-2.2,-1.5)(2.2,1.5)
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic,plotpoints=100]{-7}{7}{sin(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]